# How to Deal with Contextual Variables Causing a Slow Query

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a `dplyr` query which runs on a large data frame and it's painfully slow. Reprex:

Start with a dataframe `df` which has duplicate rows (because it was formed by a `left_join()` call). If I see a duplicate index value then the name, year and city values will be duplicated too.

```
df <- data.frame(index  = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3),
                 name   = c("Andy", "Andy", "Andy", "Bob", "Bob", "Charles"),
                 year   = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1971, 1971, 1972),
                 city   = c("Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Copenhagen"),
                 amount = c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678))
```

I want to know the sum of the amount field for each value of index. However I want to retain `name`, `year` and `city`.

```
output_i_want <- data.frame(index        = c(1, 2, 3),
                            name         = c("Andy", "Bob", "Charles"),
                            year         = c(1970, 1971, 1972),
                            city         = c("Amsterdam", "Barcelona", "Copenhagen"),
                            total_amount = c(702, 1023, 678))
```

It's easy enough to do it like this:

```
df |>
  group_by(index) |>
  summarise(name         = first(name),
            year         = first(year),
            city         = first(city),
            total_amount = sum(amount)) |>
  ungroup()
```

...but in my real world case (where `first()` appears about 20 times and `sum()` appears 8 times) it's horribly slow.

If I instead do:

```
df |>
  group_by(index) |>
  summarise(total_amount = sum(amount)) |>
  ungroup()
```

then it runs fast, but I then lose `name`, `year` and `city` - and I'm not sure how best to get them back. Do I need a different type of join afterwards, or some other technique?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Since the columns involved with `first` in the question are constant within `index` try grouping by all 4 to eliminate the need for `first`.  The code below assumes all non-grouping columns are to be summed but you could specify something like `where(is.numeric)` if all numeric non-grouping columns are to be summed or `amount1:amount3` if the columns are side by side or `starts_with("amount")` if they all start with `amount`.

```
library(dplyr) # version 1.1.0 or later

df %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), sum, .names = "total_{.col}"), .by = index:city)
```

giving:

```
  index    name year       city total_amount
1     1    Andy 1970  Amsterdam          702
2     2     Bob 1971  Barcelona         1023
3     3 Charles 1972 Copenhagen          678
```

**2)** A base solution using the same idea is the following. Change the numbers as needed.  Omit the last 2 statements if having a total_ prefix is not important.

```
ag <- aggregate(df[5], df[-5], sum)
names(ag)[5] <- paste("total", names(ag)[5], sep = "_")
ag
```

giving:

```
  index    name year       city total_amount
1     1    Andy 1970  Amsterdam          702
2     2     Bob 1971  Barcelona         1023
3     3 Charles 1972 Copenhagen          678
```